# Android Support Design v23 scroll behaviour bug

Tags: android, scroll, android-support-library, android-support-design

I have the following situation:

One coordinator layout wrapping an AppbarLayout (with content inside) and the other child is a linearlayout that wraps a recycleview.

I add the appbar_scrolling_view_behavior to the linearlayout in order to react with the scrolls of the recycler but when it reaches the top the first child of the linearlayout sticks on the top.

I achieve this, and is still working perfectly with physical devices but not in the emulator. It was working in the emulators in the last version of the library.

What is happening now is that when I'm trying to open that view, the screen starts to shake and the log output is full of this:

```
W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa1584320, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

If I place the behavior in the recylcerview then this error is not happening but then I don't get the desired situation.

I will open a ticket, but does anyone faced the same situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging I found that the issue is related to the theme together with using coordinator layout and `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

So if I set this on my theme

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

With the layout on the previous comment it happens this error.

Instead of using windowsIsFloating I set it to false and I force the activity window size

```
getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Then it works properly.